# How Can I Completly Clear A ListView Activity And It's Adapter Class Once I Go Back To Main Activity?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, adapter

I have a list which fills with some data based on a selection (filter), and it works great, but when i close the activity and open it again, the activity re-loads all those objects into memory and keep growing, what i want to do it's to clear all those items once i go back to main activity.

What i have it's someting like this:

Main Activity > ListActivity

I have a class which reads all data to be shown, and another one which it's the Adapter for the list.

The reader class, filter all data and select the data that will be shown on the list, then put the selected data into the adapter class, and the ListActivity takes the data from this adapter.

Comment: Have you tried calling `adapter.clear()` in `onDestroy()` and `onStop()`?

Comment: `adapter.removeAll()` will work, hope so

Comment: The adapter object does not give none of these options (adapter.clear() nor adapter.removeAll()).

Anyway thanks for your help.

I'm working on Xamarin (C#), but i guess it should have it.

If it's useful to know, my adapter extends from BaseAdapter (BaseAdapter<String>).

Comment: In C# functions are different, so it's possible it's not called that way (there will be something similar for sure, though). Sorry I can't help better, I don't know C# yet.

Comment: Yeah, i'm pretty sure it gotta be something like in C#, but thanks for your help, keep like that dude.

Comment: I had a similar issue where it didn't seem to be clearing up, even though it was supposed to.  I ended up calling GC.Collect() (a really ugly 'solution') in the click event for the button which opened up the list activity.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little ugly solution, but it works and that's what i need now. Thanks Dave.